# RxJS: mergeMap operator cancelling other active requests when one of them throws an error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

Based on the [article](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2018/06/way-to-handle-parallel-multiple-requests.html) 
I tried to implement parallel update logic with multiple requests to a server:

```
const prouctIds: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
const requests = from(prouctIds)
    .pipe(mergeMap(id => /* Emulating error when updating some entity*/ throwError(id + '/err')));
requests.subscribe(success => console.log(success), err => console.error('error block', err));
```

As the author said:

> So if there is any request fails i.e. throws server side error, then it doesn't affect other parallel requests.

But in my case if some of the requests returns an error, other active requests are cancelling. If you run the code snippet above, you can notice one error message in console only.

1. I know that I can use `forkJoin` with inner `catchError` pipe, but
   what then is the difference between these operators if `mergeMap`
   also cancels parallel requests if an error occurred in one of them?
2. How to achieve my goal without using inner `catchError` pipe and transform the error to a regular observable, i.e. `catchError(err => of(err));`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to transform an error to a regular observable without catching the error and returning a regular observable???

Comment: @fridoo I want to send n parallel requests based on the array of my model. If some of them is failed, don't cancel the orhers. Get all succeeded responses in subscribe success callback, all errors responses in subscribe failed callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the RxJS documentation:

> "Error" and "Complete" notifications may happen only once during the
>   Observable Execution, and there can only be either one of them.
>
> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be
>   delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered,
>   then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.
>   [[RxJS Documentation - Observable]](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

So you can't have an Observable call the error callback multiple times, as the article you posted suggests. You have to use an inner `catchError` to return an Observable that doesn't error.

Use `mergeMap` or `merge` instead of `forkJoin` if you want to get responses as soon as they arrive because `forkJoin` only emits when all inner Observables completed.

Comment: Ha! How much already developing using RxJS, never thought about it. It is unfortunate that the author is misleading regarding the `mergeMap` operator. Thanks anyway for your reply!